# GIve permission to use Camera access to chromium launched through Playwright

Tags: windows, robotframework, playwright

I'm using robot framework with playwright (browser) on Windows.

I'm trying to allow the usage of the web cam, that message appears on a popup window, like this:

[image]

Anyone can help me to handle this kind of popups?

Thanks
Joao

Answer (score 1):

You should be easily able to give access to camera using [browser-context-grant-permissions](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-grant-permissions) api.

You just need to update `playwright.config.ts` file where you set up browser under different project.

```
{
   name: 'chromium',
   use:{
      permissions: ["camera"]
   }
}
```

You can also provide the permission of microphone together like below

```
 {
      name: 'chromium',
      use:{
        permissions: ["microphone","camera"]
      }
}
```

Comment: I was facing a similar issue and tried the above solution, the tests seem to succeed for Chromium browser but still fail for WebKit.